# Kafka dynamic consumer issue

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have been developing a kafka producer and consumer in a spring boot application. I can send data to topic dynamically but can't consume data from the topic dynamically

Through controller we are requesting topic name and message to send to topic.
And through other endpoint we are requesting topic name for the receiver to get message it gets this error:
String topicName
@KafkaListener(topics=topicName)

Following is the error
The value for annotation attribute kafkaListener.topics must be a constant